# Append a text on the node PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, pixi.js

I have recently started a simple project to plot network graphs using PIXI.js. I'm new to the PIXI.js so am not very sure how to fully utilise the library yet. One of the projects on bl.ocks.org spark my interest:
https://bl.ocks.org/kirjavascript/dcafa2b3a53cbcc9c5de19b938b92119

Is there any way that I can display the name of the node.
I manage to do it but the text does not clear and just stays on the window.

> How do I clear the text such that whenever the node is drag, the old
>   position of the text is cleared?

The screenshot below is a snippet of the output.
[image]

I edit the ticked function and produce this result. The code below is a snippet of the `ticked()` function:

```
function ticked() {   
    graph.nodes.forEach((node) => {
        var { x, y, gfx } = node;
        gfx.position = new PIXI.Point(x, y);

        var text = new PIXI.Text(node.id, textStyle);                        
        text.x = x;
        text.y = y;                                            
        stage.addChild(text);                            
    });

    links.clear();
    links.alpha = 0.6;                                    

    graph.links.forEach((link) => {
        var { source, target } = link;
        links.lineStyle(1.5, 0x000000);
        links.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
        links.lineTo(target.x, target.y);
    });                                    

    links.endFill();

    renderer.render(stage);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new PIXI.Text instance every tick. You only want to create 1 text instance per node, then re-use it.

ps. for setting position, do

```
gfx.position.set(x, y);
```

to save creating needless PIXI.Points each tick too.